# Save Nano File on Terminal through 'ssh'

Tags: key-bindings, ssh

I've accessed a server through the `ssh` mode in Emacs. I need to create and save a file on the server.  I can open a file through `nano <filename>` and start to type. However, I'm unable to close & save the file.  Nano states that I should use `C-x` to close but that key sequence is interrupted by Emacs which waits for a further command & I can't find anyway to enter `C-x` as an alternative.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not quite sure what ssh mode is.  It sounds like you're opening either `term`, `shell`, or `eshell` and then sshing to a remote host.  It's important to know which for further help.  Also, you should look into tramp (quick answer: `C-x C-f /ssh:user@host:/path/to/file`).

Comment: Hello.  How I enter this mode is by using the command 'M-x ssh RET'.  I then have to type in the hostname and password.

Comment: I'm not able to check now because I think I downloaded it through the internal emacs package manager and I haven't my laptop.  But I think this is the mode that I'm using: https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/04/18/emacs-ssh-mode-package/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ssh-mode is based on `shell` (and it [seems](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/04/18/emacs-ssh-mode-package/) like it is), nano (or vim or any terminal-based editor) is not going to work well.  Same with `eshell`.  It seems like you can type control characters with `C-q` (`quoted-insert`), e.g. `C-q C-x RET` for `C-x`.

You're better off with `term`, because it's actually a terminal emulator (`shell` and `eshell` are not).  Just `M-x term`, run `ssh` in there, and do what you want.  Note that a lot of Emacs keybindings are different in `term`; switch to `term-line-mode` (`C-c C-j`) to make it more like a normal buffer and get your keybinds back.

You're even more better off with tramp, because it makes editing remote files almost seamless.

Comment: The quoted-insert solution worked for the immediate problem but I found that ssh mode still had problems working with 'nano' remotely.  Ultimately I ended up diving into tramp and found that it worked well with editing files remotely.  My recommendation for anyone else reading this answer is to learn how to use tramp.  Thanks jpkotta!